# How to set value in table in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I selected project as WindowsBased application from Xcode. I have to views in first views i have only button and in second views i have to show values in TableNavigation. I create my first view with simple WindowBased application selection. From the first screen i am able to load my second screen. I am loading secondScreen.xib file on button click event. This is loading successfully. In secondScreen.xib file i have table view. When application is runnig this is showing blank. I have to to set some values in Row and Column. How will i do this ? I have written a function code but i don't know how will i load this function when secondScreen is loading. I was selected New File --> UIViewController SubClass for secondScreen.

```
-(void) fillList {  
    NSArray *tempArr=[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",nil]autorelease];
    self.tableList=tempArr;
}

My interface structure is like here.


@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *tableList;
}


@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *tableList;


-(void) fillList;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [tutorial](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2010/10/uitableview.html).

In order to display a `UITableView`, you need to setup a [data source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and, possibly, a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). The data source is responsible to provide your table with the rows it should display. Read the tutorial to understand how the data source can be defined step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Download the book for free from the given below link and read it, this will helps you learning basics for iphone development
[Book Link](http://www.4shared.com/document/_Kr0oTTm/Beginning_iPhone_3_Development.html)